# Ruby while loop only executes once with break if statement

Tags: ruby, rhomobile

I am trying to continue while loop for 3 times. If I get data from server the loop should break. But in the below code while loop terminates after responding one time. What should I do?

```
@i = 0
while @i < 3
  udp_socket.send req_param[:msg], req_param[:flag], req_param[:url], req_param[:port]
    @i +=1
    puts "#{@i}"
    if udp_socket.recvfrom(100)
      break
    end
end 
  for j in 0..1
  resp = udp_socket.recvfrom(100)
  puts "resp:#{resp.inspect}"
 end
udp_socket.close
return resp
```

Comment: What is the return of this line: `udp_socket.recvfrom(100)`? Because this is the condition to break, even before the 3rd time.

Comment: the return of the line you asked is immediate ack from server(i.e a simple string like "1200")

Comment: So, it always respond with a String? If yes, then the condition will always be true, and the while will be terminated the first time.

Comment: yes you are right while loop will terminate at any instance when it gets response but if not then while loop will continue for 3 times and also the time interval between every single request should be 3 sec.How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`recvfrom`(inherited from the parent `IPSocket`) would block until it gets data (unless nonblock option is set). Which means that it would be a non-falsy return, and break. It will always wait until there is data and break.

Perhaps you meant to non-block? - calling the `recvfrom_nonblock` method instead?

Comment: I had checked with recvfrom_nonblock but its showing error.Error: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. - recvfrom(2) would block

Comment: Which means it is going to block until it times out or gets something - and then break - it will only take 3 retries if it times out - unless that generates an exception.

Comment: can you write a sample udp code for sending request to server and then upto when you will not recieve response from server it will send same request 3 times after every 3 sec for 5 times to same server?

Comment: The clue is here - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html - and you could then use the ruby rescue -> retry syntax, with a condition on the max number of times. Rescue from the IO::WaitReadable condition. There is sample code for that in the linked doc.

Comment: I tried with this code but I am getting void value exception. `if udp_socket.recvfrom(100) == nil
      @i = 0
      while @i < 3
        udp_socket.send req_param[:msg], req_param[:flag], req_param[:url], req_param[:port]
        @i +=1
        puts "#{@i}"
      end
    elsif
    break
    end`

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code, it seems you're not updating `resp` variable inside `while` loop, change code to something like this instead:

```
j = 1
resp = udp_socket.recvfrom(100)
if resp
  udp_socket.close
  return resp
end
while j < 3
  udp_socket.send req_param[:msg], req_param[:flag], req_param[:url], req_param[:port]
  resp = udp_socket.recvfrom(100)
  j += 1
  puts "ok"
  break if resp  
end
puts "resp:#{resp.inspect}"
```

Comment: I am able to achieve somewhat but still it sending request 2 times with this code `    @i = 0
    $var = nil 
    
    Thread.new do  
    while @i < 3
      udp_socket.send req_param[:msg], req_param[:flag], req_param[:url], req_param[:port]
        @i +=1
        puts "#{@i}"
        puts "#{$var}"
       if ($var != nil)
         break 
       end
    end
  end
    $var = udp_socket.recvfrom(100)`

Comment: I want to write a ruby code in which first i send a request to server then wait for 5sec to get response from server. 
If i get the response from server then it will perform next task and if i not get the response in 5sec then the same request will be sended to server for 4 times in interval of 3 sec. 
While sending the request for 4 time if i get the response at any instance it will stop sending request further to server. Can you help me in writing the code for this.